# SQL retrieve record if it has specific pattern

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB which contains following column

```
message     varchar(300)    latin1_general_ci
```

I want to retrieve all messages which contain a specific string pattern, e.g. "@test".
The pattern (@test) may be anywhere in the string.

Is this possible with SQL or do I have to do this in PHP by iterating over all entries?

Comment: '@test' is in middle or it start with '@test'i imean what patter you talk

Comment: It is possible with LIKE but contains-substring searches are not sargable.

Comment: I have updated the post. The pattern can be anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all such records by using following statement

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `message` LIKE '%@test%'
```

This query will return all records that contain `@test` anywhere in `message` field value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the like keyword with wildcards.

```
where myfield like '%@test%'
```

The percentage sign is the wildcard.